# Why export s3 bucket name and arn use different syntax in serverless framework?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, serverless-framework

I have below configuration for `serverless.yml`. It creates a s3 bucket and exports its ARN and Name. What I don't understand is why the bucket ARN value is get by `Fn::GetAtt:: S3Bucket Arn` but the bucket name is get by `Ref S3Bucket`. What is the different between these two syntax?

```
...
  Outputs:
    AttachmentsBucketArn:
      Value:
         Fn::GetAtt:
          - S3Bucket
          - Arn
      Export:
        Name: ${self:custom.stage}-ExtAttachmentsBucketArn

    AttachmentsBucketName:
      Value:
        Ref: S3Bucket
      Export:
        Name: ${self:custom.stage}-ExtAttachmentsBucket
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They map directly to return values of [AWS::S3::Bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket.html#aws-properties-s3-bucket-return-values) in CloudFormation.

As the link explains, the use of:

- [Ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-ref.html) "returns the bucket name"
- [GetAtt](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-getatt.html)  with `Arn` "returns the Amazon Resource Name (ARN) of the specified bucket."